# Assembly not found even when automatic binding is enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an Azure Function which is failing with a could not find assembly error for

```
System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

This package is correctly referenced in both my Azure Function and in the class library that has the code

I have this in both project files

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

How can I fix this really frustrating issue?

I have referenced System.ComponentModel.Annotations package

There doesnt seem to be much around about how to do assembly redirecting inside Azure functions

I am using Azure Functions V3 in a .NET Core 3.1 system

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because the version of nugget does not match the version of the generated library. You can try the following:

1.From package manage console do:

```
Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect
```

to regenerate `assemblyBinding` configuration at the config file

2.If didn't fix it, then add manually the binding redirection.
Make changes according to the version you need to specify

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations"
                      publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

oldVersion:Specifies the version of the assembly that was originally requested

newVersion:Specify the assembly version to be used

Comment: Thanks for this but its XML?  I thought that .NET Core 3.1 uses json config?

Comment: Binding redirects are a .NET framework concept, there are no binding redirects on .NET Standard and .NET Core.If a binding redirect is necessary, they have to be added to the .NET Framework application (or library) that used the .NET Standard library.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999